# How to bind aura enabled property to lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute

```
@AuraEnabled
public string prop { get; set;}
```

I need to bind above apex controller property to lightning component. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a method to set the value from VF page.

```
@AuraEnabled

public static CLASSNAME GetProp ()

{

CLASSNAME result = new CLASSNAME();

result.prop = value;


return result;

}

In the component:

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute type="CLASSNAME" name="var" />
    Value is = {!v.var.prop}
</aura:component>

In the controller:

doInit : function(cmp, ev) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.GetProp");

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.var', response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                alert('Error : ' + JSON.stringify(errors));
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Component or App can use the controller property by using `<aura:attribute/>`

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="prop" type="String"/>
</aura:component>
```

For more information refer [Lightning Components Basics](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_attributes_expressions) Trailhead or [Component Attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm)

Comment: In his question, he says he's asking about an APEX controller's property, which is different than the JS property in his Lightning Controller. Might be a mistatement in his question, but clearly not the same.